# How to pass data from an api as array in setText

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I'm trying to pass multiple data to a single setText, separated by comma. I was able to get the results and display them in a log, but I do not know how to put on all together.

**Example**: Comedy, Adventure

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Data data = response.body();

                for (Movie movie : data.getData()) {//iterate through all movies
                    Attributes attributes = movie.getAttributes();
                    Log.i("INFO", attributes.getName());
                    textGeners.setText(attributes.getName());
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

`textGeners.append(attributes.getName()+", ");`
 
or use

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            Data data = response.body();
            StringBuilder attrs = new StringBuilder();
            for (Movie Movie : data.getData()) {
                Attributes attributes = movie.getAttributes();
                Log.i("INFO", attributes.getName());
                attrs.append(attributes.getName() + ", ");
            }
             textGeners.setText(attrs.toString());
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. But how do I remove the last comma?

Comment: this is one solution to get red off the last comma, attrs.substring(0,attrs.length() -1 )

Comment: One way would be like this for appending `attrs.length() == 0 ? attrs.append(attributes.getName()) : 
 "," + attrs.append(attributes.getName() );` also look into `TextUtils.join()` function in Android

Answer (score 1):

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Data data = response.body();
                String s = ""; int i = 0;
                for (Movie movie : data.getData()) {//iterate through all movies
                    Attributes attributes = movie.getAttributes();
                    if( i < 1)
                    {
                       s += attributes.getName();
                    }else{
                         s+= ","+attributes.getName(); // this will ignore the last ','
                    }

                    Log.i("INFO", attributes.getName()); i++;
                }
                textGeners.setText(s);

            }
```